# Windows Form Application with Console Application

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, console-application

I have a console application that asks for a **SourcePath** when started.. when I enter the Source Path, It asks for **DestinationPath**... when i enter DestinationPath it starts some execution

My Problem is to Supply these path via a windows application, means i need to create a window form application that will supply these parameters to the console application automatiocally after certain time interval

can it be achieved or not... if yes, plese help... its very Urgent...

ohh.. 
I have tried a lot of code that i can not paste hear all but some that i use to start the application are...

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wondershare\PPT2Flash SDK\ppt2flash.exe";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
            psi.Arguments = input + ";" + output;
        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

and

```
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wondershare\PPT2Flash SDK\ppt2flash.exe",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            }
        };
        if (process.Start())
        {
            Redirect(process.StandardError, text);
            Redirect(process.StandardOutput, text);
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    private void Redirect(StreamReader input, string output)
    {
        new Thread(a =>{var buffer = new char[1];
            while (input.Read(buffer, 0, 1) > 0)
            {
                output += new string(buffer);
            };
        }).Start();
    }
```

but nothing seems to be working

Comment: It can be achieved. But we canot help with you more details unless you let us know what you have tried.

Comment: i added what i tried
any help

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you need to supply the console app parameters when you start it from the forms? and you would want to automate this?

Comment: yes... this is what i want.. is it possible ???

Comment: @ryadavilli i am not asking the code.. i am just asking the technique or a little explanation of the process... it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters to your ProcessStartInfo like this:

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\MyConsoleApp.exe",
     @"C:\MyLocationAsFirstParamter C:\MyOtherLocationAsSecondParameter");
 Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

this will startup the console app with 2 parameters.
Now in your console app you have the

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
```

the string array args is what contains the parameters, now all you have to do is get them when your app starts.

```
if (args == null || args.Length < 2)
{
    //the arguments are not passed correctly, or not at all
}
else
{
    try
    {
        yourFirstVariable = args[0];
        yourSecondVariable = args[1];
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong with setting the variables.")
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This may or may not be the exact code that you need, but at least will give you an insight in how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: yes this code may be working but not fit for my application.. because where i can make change is my Window form Application,.... Console application can not be modified because i have to Use its .exe only...
and this my main problem

Comment: do you have any suggestion.. if yes help please its very urgent

Comment: so you do not have the actual source code of the Console application before you build it?

Comment: yes you are right
that why i need to do like what i explained

Comment: I'm afraid I wouldn't know an answer in that case. But are you sure that the build console.exe doesn't include suppport of any startup params? or does the console.exe have any public documentation available so i can read into it?

Comment: thanks everyone for your kind and intelligent suggestions...   i solved my problem with a simple tick butt could not do like what i wanted